# Remote Ubuntu Desktop 17.10, how to access it with ssh and GUI

Tags: ssh, 17.10, windows-10, remote-desktop

As title says, I have a windows machine and a remote ubuntu that I access via ssh. It got the moment where I need to run some visualization software on it. How can I access the remote with a GUI (GNOME, if possible) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to install **VNC** to make GUI connection easily from Windows and Mac even another Linux machine
check this tutorial for more help 
[How to Install and Configure VNC on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-ubuntu-16-04)

same way to install it on 17.10